# NameError: name 'random_normal' is not defined Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/var/data/",one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1=500
n_nodes_hl2=500
n_nodes_hl3=500

n_classes=10
batch_size=100

#height* width
x=tf.placeholder('float',[None,784]) #28*28
y=tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
    #(input_data*weight)+biases
    hidden_1_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
    hidden_3_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
    output_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1=tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer[ 'biases'])
    l1=tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2=tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer[ 'biases'])
    l2=tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3=tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer[ 'biases'])
    l3=tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output=matmul(l3,output_layer['weight']), output_layer[ 'biases']

    return output   

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction=neural_network_model(x)
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_logits(prediction,y))

    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs=10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in hm_epochs:
            epoch_loss=0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y =mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c =sess,run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict ={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch',epoch, 'complete out of', hm_epochs, 'loss',epoch_loss)
        correct= tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmx(y,1))
        accuracy= tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))



train_neural_network(x)
```

this my code and when compile show this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "frist.py", line 63, in
>   
>       train_neural_network(x)   File "frist.py", line 40, in train_neural_network
>       prediction=neural_network_model(x)   File "frist.py", line 21, in neural_network_model
>       hidden_1_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
>   NameError: name 'random_normal' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `tf.` in front of `random_normal` in these lines (in the second `tf.Variable` call)

```
hidden_1_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
hidden_2_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
hidden_3_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
output_layer={'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])), 'biases':tf.Variable(random_normal([n_classes]))}
```